# How to plot the shapefile via ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, raster, shapefile

I have a raster data and polygons of parks and I want to overlap it on the raster. When I add the polygon it shows here but on ggplot how I add polygons (polygons of parks is like round shapes)on my raster data through ggplot2,. My code is attached below.

```
   r <- raster(t((volcano[,ncol(volcano):1] - 94) * 4.95))
   pg <- readOGR("E:/park/1aa.shp") # loadshapfile 
   plot(r)
   plot(pg, add= TRUE,) # it appears here like first picture (left).
```

[image]

But how can I add this polygons o parks in my ggplot 2. My code of ggplot 2 is  attached below.

```
  centile90 <- quantile(r, 0.90)
  df <- as.data.frame(as(r, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"))
  colnames(df) <- c("value", "x", "y")
  library(ggplot2)

   mybreaks <- seq(0, 500, 50)

   ggplot(df, aes(x, y, z = value)) +
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = mybreaks) +
  geom_contour(breaks = centile90, colour = "pink",
          size = 0.5) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = hcl.colors(length(mybreaks) - 3, "Zissou1", rev = FALSE)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme()
```

Help is needed how to add ** pg (polygon) ** in my ggplot2 code.

**Update 1**
Description of polygon data

[image]

Comment: This is not a reproducible example. Please provide an example that others can run. We do not have access to these data.

Comment: I have made changes and try to make it reproducible please have a look on it.

Comment: Because the developer of `sp` has basically deprecated that package and is focusing all new development on the newer `sf` package, it's now easier to plot polygons on `ggplot2` plots using `sf` instead of `sp`. Try reading your shapefile in with `sf::st_read()` instead of `readOGR`, then you can add a `geom_sf()` to your plot. See https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf5.html

Comment: I understand but my question is how I write **geom_sf()** in my code of ggplot? In which line of code I need to add this function to plot my shapefile on raster image. Sorry for poor English and poor programming sense @qdread.

Comment: It's hard to know without reproducible example (we don't have access to your shapefile) but try `pg <- st_read('1aa.shp`)` then add `+ geom_sf(data = pg, fill = NA)` to your ggplot.

Comment: Shapefile is just ** Spatialpolygondataframe**. Picture of polygon is attached above with their description. If possible can you use any random raster image and overlaid any shape file on it and then run this above code by some editing to make in ggplot function? @gdread

Comment: I have made changes in code you can see again @gdread

Comment: Could you please share your `1aa.shp` file? So we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained, it is much handy to work with `sf` than `sp`, on top of that `sf` is meant to superseed `sp`.

Find here a reproducible example. The first part is just for mocking your file `"E:/park/1aa.shp"`. Since it was not provided it was not possible for me to use your real data, but let's just pretend it is the same dataset...:

```r
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(sp)

r <- raster(t((volcano[,ncol(volcano):1] - 94) * 4.95))

# Let's mock your shapefile
poly <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(st_as_sf(rasterToPolygons(r))))

# Sample 4 points
set.seed(3456)

sample <- st_sample(poly, 4)
sample <- st_buffer(sample, c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03))
sample <- st_sf(x=1:4, sample)
st_write(sample, "1aa.shp", append = FALSE)
# Mocked data

# Now let's start with your code -------
library(raster)
library(sf)

r <- raster(t((volcano[,ncol(volcano):1] - 94) * 4.95))

# Use sf!!
pg <- st_read("1aa.shp") # loadshapfile 
plot(r)
plot(st_geometry(pg), add= TRUE,) # it appears here like first picture (left).
```

[image]

Now work with `geom_sf()` on your `pg` object:

```r
centile90 <- quantile(r, 0.90)
df <- as.data.frame(as(r, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"))
colnames(df) <- c("value", "x", "y")

library(ggplot2)

mybreaks <- seq(0, 500, 50)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, z = value)) +
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = mybreaks) +
  geom_contour(breaks = centile90, colour = "pink",
               size = 0.5) +
  # And here we have it
  geom_sf(data=pg, fill="black", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = hcl.colors(length(mybreaks)-1, "Zissou1", rev = FALSE)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme()
```

[image]

Comment: @diegernan It really works for me. Can you tell me last one thing please how I can add the different colors manually in my this code. The color scheme  of **Zissou1** is not good for my data. I want to add this colour scheme **"#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7"** these colours.  Need your help in this last matter

Comment: Sure, try using `scale_fill_manual(values = c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7"))` but be sure that the number of colors matches the number of elements on `my_breaks`. You may need to adjust either the breaks or the colors

Comment: I think you will need 9 colors with your current setup, so one more

Comment: Its really work for me and thanks for detail answering @dieghernan